# Enable MySQL General Log on Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-rds

I found these instructions to turn it on:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

But the Edit Parameters button is disabled:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the name "default.mysql5.6," it looks like you are trying to edit the default parameter group.

> You cannot modify the parameter settings of a default DB parameter group; you must create your own DB parameter group to change parameter settings from their default value.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html